# Cisco 3750 switch to Cisco 1841 router to Cable Modem?

Tags: cisco, routing, network-core

I was rushing to help a friend out today who was trying to get a 3750 attached to a 1841 behind a cable modem. He called me at the last minute and figured it would be simple considering his needs were so basic.

1841 is the router, connecting to cable modem. Setup a couple of vlan subinterfaces on the 1841 as well as dhcp pools. Attached the 3750 to the router with a trunk link and passed the vlans.  Associated the vlans to ports and did some basic static routes. I was rushed, under a time crunch to get my daughter and well ran into a problem reaching internet from PC. Panicking about my time and not seeing clearly to troubleshoot or figure it out.

Basics are that PC was getting IP from the 1841 via DHCP.  PC could ping vlan subinterface gateway, 192.168.1.1.  PC could ping the Fa0/0 IP. Which is an external IP.

Router **could** ping internet 8.8.8.8 with a basic "ping 8.8.8.8"

Router **could NOT** ping internet when I sourced from VLAN 100 subinterface (192.168.1.1)

Not sure what I'm missing but I'm missing something.  So much for 20 years of experience sometimes. Thought this would be the easiest network deployment I've done in 15 years.

The fact I couldn't ping internet from the internal subinterface bugs me. Issue on the PC seems secondary to the fact I couldn't get the local subinterface to work either.  So its got to just be something on the 1841 at a minimum.

Here is the config of the 1841:

```
FT-ROUTER#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2394 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname FT-ROUTER
!
boot-start-marker
boot system flash c1841-ipbasek9-mz.124-20.T.bin
boot-end-marker
!
logging message-counter syslog
!
no aaa new-model
ip source-route
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1 192.168.3.5
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.5
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.5
!         
ip dhcp pool MAINDATA
   network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.1.1 
   dns-server 68.105.28.16 68.105.29.16 
!
ip dhcp pool PUBLICWIFI
   network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.2.1 
   dns-server 68.105.28.16 68.105.29.16 
!
ip dhcp pool SECURITY
   network 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.3.1 
   dns-server 68.105.28.16 68.105.29.16 
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
!

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 98.190.71.2 255.255.255.240
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.100
 description FT-MAIN-DATA
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.200
 description FT-PUBLIC-WIRELESS
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.300
 encapsulation dot1Q 300
 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!

!
ip default-gateway 98.190.71.1
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 98.190.71.1
!
ip nat inside source list 10 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

Here is a basic diagram:

[image: Network Diagram]

Any glaring omissions or thoughts?  I am going to go back out and try to help him tomorrow. Trying to get my thoughts right tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the missing `ip nat outside` command suggested by Ron Trunk, you are only allowing NAT Overload on VLAN 100.

If you want to allow NAT Overload and allow Internet access on VLAN 200 and VLAN 300 you will need to adjust your ACL to include those additional subnets.

Original Code:

```
access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

Recommend changing to:

```
access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255
```

**To answer your second question:**

Below is a regular Static PAT statement.

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.3.50 8080 98.190.71.2 8080 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.3.51 8081 98.190.71.2 8081 extendable
```

These may also be needed for UDP traffic.

```
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.3.50 8080 98.190.71.2 8080 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.3.51 8081 98.190.71.2 8081 extendable
```

Comment: You keep using the term "PAT" that doesn't really exist. The RFCs call it NAPT (Network Address Port Translation). Cisco calls it NAT-PT (Network Address Translation - Port Translation).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the command

```
ip nat outside
```

On the external interface Fa 0/0

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!  Thank you both.

Any ideas on how I can allow in a couple of ports mapped to internal addresses?

Apparently security cameras need ports 8080 allowed in to 192.168.3.50

And 8081 allowed into 192.168.3.51